# What elisp or macro magic can make this text transformation?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, text-formatting

I have a set of SQL statements formatted like so:

```
INSERT INTO reports.workload (workload_id,event_time,event_type_id,agent_id) VALUES 
                             (-42000,'2010-02-23 07:30:38.941436',1,NULL);
```

Right now, the VALUES tuple is aligned at the start with the column name tuple. However, what I want is to have the tuple's *elements* aligned as well, like so:

```
INSERT INTO reports.workload (workload_id,event_time,                  event_type_id,agent_id) VALUES 
                             (-42000,     '2010-02-23 07:30:38.941436',1            ,NULL);
```

My elisp-fu and regexp-fu are moderate, but not sufficient to this task. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the `INSERT … SET` form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the region you'd like to align, and type <kbd>C-u C-x \</kbd> (that is a shortcut for `align-regexp`). Choose `\(,\)` as regex pattern and repeat it throughout line.

For more on text align, see chapter [AlignCommands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands) in EmacsWiki.